# SSRS Tablix calculated field issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to create a Tablix report.  In this report I have two fields that I pull data for and another one that I want to be a calculated field.  Here is what the Tablix looks like:

```
Location     Item Count     % Difference
ORD          100            0
MDT          90             10
RN4          80             20
```

The query to pull this data is simple:

```
SELECT
    IFLOC AS Location,
    COUNT(IFITEM) AS ItemCount
FROM
    dbo.S2K_IB
WHERE
    IFDEL <> 'I'
GROUP BY
    IFLOC
ORDER BY
    ItemCount DESC
```

My issue is the % Difference column.  I want it to always find the difference in Location ORD as it relates to the other locations.  Meaning, Location ORD will always have the highest Item Count and I want to know the difference between the other two locations as they relate to Location ORD.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: any other locations other than these, like numeric 1 or 2?

Comment: No, there are only three locations and the field is char(3) on the table.

Comment: okay where did location A go?

Comment: I changed the values to the actual values in case that made any difference.  I also resorted the query so the highest number of Item Count will be first.

Comment: The last lines of your question still say Location A. which location is the base on which you want the percentage?

Comment: Sorry for that.  ORD will be the location that will always have the highest ItemCount.

Comment: I have my answer edited check now and please comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the query has the `Location` grouped and ordered.
You can use the following expression in this case.

```
=(first(Fields!ItemCount.Value, "DataSet1")-Fields!ItemCount.Value)/first(Fields!ItemCount.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Make sure to change the textbox format to percentage.